# Unhandled Promise Rejection TypeError undefined is not an object (evaluating services drugSearchService getDrugsByCriteria(criteria, val).then)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rest, axios

DrugSearchService.js

```
import axios from "axios";
    const DRUG_GENERIC_API_URL ='http://localhost:8080/drug/search/generic/'
    const DRUG_MAIN_API_URL ='http://localhost:8080/drug/search/main/'

    class DrugSearchService{
        getDrugsByCriteria(criteria,val){
            if(criteria == 'Main'){
                return axios.get(DRUG_MAIN_API_URL+val);
            }else if(criteria == 'Generic'){
                return axios.get(DRUG_GENERIC_API_URL+val);
            }
        
        }
    }

export default new DrugSearchService()
```

DrugSearch.vue

```
    <template>
    <div class="input-group">
            <input v-model="val" type="text">
            <select v-model="criteria">
                <option value="Main" selected>Main Name</option>
                <option value="Generic">Generic Name</option>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" v-on:click="get_Drugs_by_criteria()">Search</button>
    </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import drugSearchService from '@/services/drugSearchService';
    export default{
        name:'Drugs_by_criteria',
        data(){
            return{
                criteria:'',
                val : '',
                drugsByCriteria:[]
            }
        },
        methods:{
            get_Drugs_by_criteria(){
                // drugSearchService.getDrugsByCriteria(this.criteria,this.val).then((response)=>{
                drugSearchService.getDrugsByCriteria('Main','Loratadine').then((response)=>{
                    this.drugsByCriteria = response.data;
                });
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.get_Drugs_by_criteria()
        }
    }

</script>
```

error:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object
> (evaluating'*services_drugSearchService__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_["default"].getDrugsByCriteria(this.criteria,
> this.val).then')

want to use like this

`drugSearchService.getDrugsByCriteria(this.criteria,this.val).then((response)=>{`

but getting error. but same method with static data is working like this
`drugSearchService.getDrugsByCriteria('Main','Loratadine').then((response)=>{`

what's wrong in this
`drugSearchService.getDrugsByCriteria(this.criteria,this.val).then((response)=>{`

Answer (score 0):

i initialized criteria and val with some value. and its working now.

```
data(){
    return{
        criteria:'Main',
        val : 'Metformin',
        drugsByCriteria:[]
    }
},
```